# How to get the specific text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am try to get the specific text using jquery, Here is my code,

```
<div class='sometext'>
sometext
<span class="innerspan">span_text</span>

</div>
```

From the above html I need to get the **sometext** using jquery like this,

```
$('.sometext').text()
```

But I received the output **sometextspan_text**.

How to get the **sometext** only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the first node you can find, which is a text node in your case:

```
$('.sometext').contents().get(0);
```

This is a bit fragile, so another approach is by first getting all child text nodes:

```
$('.sometext').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});
```

And then take the first of that:

```
$('.sometext').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
})[0];
```

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know about `contents()` :) +1. Also just as a side note -> `.contents()[0]` works as well.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Yeah, array dereferencing works too :)

Comment: would it be possible to use :contains() jquery selector?

Comment: @chepe no, that's a conditional selector, i.e. it matches a search string.

Answer (score -1):

I think you shoul organize every text nodes inside ".sometext" div, for example inside a div or p tag like the following:

```
<div class='sometext'><p>sometext</p><span class="innerspan">span_text</span></div>
```

Then you'll be able to access ".sometext" div's children with the [JQuery Children function](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

```
$(".sometext").children()[0]
```

The index depends of the position of the element inside the di, I suggest you read the docs of the function. Hope this helps you my friend!

Answer (score -1):

Please see the code below.

```
$('.sometext')
        .contents()
        .filter(function(){
             return this.nodeType == 1; 
        }).hide();
```